# how to get current time of a UAE in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, yii

I am using yii framework

I am using  below to code to get time

```
<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s') ?>
```

how can i current time of `UAE`?

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
$tz = 'Asia/Dubai'; // your required location time zone.
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
echo $dt->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
echo "The time is " . date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```